# Extract the data analysis dataset

Tags: postgresql

Hello everyone my name is Oluchi, Am new to programming, been trying to:

Write a SQL query that returns: the user ID, the user’s country, the user’s gender, the user’s device type, the user’s test group, whether or not they converted (spent > $0), and how much they spent in total ($0+).

But am not getting it right

I tried:

```
SELECT user_id, country, gender, device_type, test_group, 

CASE 
WHEN total_spent > 0THEN 1
ELSE AS converted, 
COALESCE(total_spent,0)AS total_spent
FROM users
LEFT JOIN activity 
ON users.id = users.id
GROUP BY user_id, country, gender, device_type, test_group;
```

Comment: can you join the tables structure?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, the expected results of that data, and the actual results. All as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), but - **no images**.